# Increase Sqlite upper limit for attached databases

Tags: sqlite

I need a sqlite3 database with over 1000 attached databases, but documentation says *"The maximum number of attached databases cannot be increased above 125"*

Some earlier versions talk about limit 63

Is this upper limit is artificial? I am able to compile sqlite after removing code that gives this limit, but is it safe?

We talk about limit because of performance or is there a deeper, hidden problem after crossing limit 125?

Comment: Just curious, How did it come about that you need to attach so many databases? Could they be restructured to make the issue easier?

Comment: I wanted single file for every table to improve write performance.

Comment: Please note that attached databases increase the transaction overhead, so writes with multiple databases are likely to be slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of deeper, hidden problems. For example, a cursor uses a signed 8-bit integer to hold the index of the database it refers to. 127 is the maximum value for a signed 8-bit integer.